# Redshift numeric overflow on prepared statement

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am seeing this error when I try to do a bulk insert into Redshift with a prepared statement

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES (?, ?, ?, ...)
```

> ERROR: Numeric data overflow (maximum 38 digits)(File /home/ec2-user/padb/src/sys/xen_execute.cpp; Line 8288; Routine pg_throw; )

How can I troubleshoot this or track down which column/value causes the problem?

Note that if I insert the same data one row at a time with literals (`insert into table values(x, y, z ..)`) then it doesn't break.

Comment: can you create a version of your table with all varchar(max) - then do the same insert - then look at the values that were adde then report back here - look for values that are longer than expected! i am expecting you have something like 1.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 or something similar

Comment: this may turn out to be a cryptic error for a type mismatch.  The actual value retrieved from one Redshift table is an `INTEGER` while the prepared statement is attempting to insert that value into a `DECIMAL(10,0)` column.  The detailed error in `STL_ERROR` is somewhat nonsensical (mantissa=1, scale=254) and the actual values are all integers.